# dot net command: net use - How to only get Alphabet and pathname?

Tags: cmd, path

When I do a "net use" on my command prompt, it will display the following:

```
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           W:        \\hfs2\ATS\Novell Profile Backup\wk\one\two\three\four\five\six\seven\eight\nine\ten\eleven\twelve\thirteen 
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
OK           X:        \\hfs2\ATS\Novell Profile Backup\wk\one\two\three\four\five\six\seven\eight\nine\ten 
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Y:        \\hfs2\ATS\Novell Profile Backup 
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
Unavailable  Z:        \\hfs2\ATS                Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

How do I extract ONLY get the drive alphabet and pathname?

```
W:        
\\hfs2\ATS\Novell Profile Backup\wk\one\two\three\four\five\six\seven\eight\nine\ten\eleven\twelve\thirteen

X:        
\\hfs2\ATS\Novell Profile Backup\wk\one\two\three\four\five\six\seven\eight\nine\ten

Y:        
\\hfs2\ATS\Novell Profile Backup

Z:        
\\hfs2\ATS
```

Comment: "dot net command" and the .net tag seem to imply you're asking how to do this from a .NET language like C# or VB.NET. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

**WMIC does not require administrator rights**

It does require rights for what you are trying to do. You can't use it to do admin things if not an admin.

It also requires an administrator to run it once on a system to set it up.

*From Help*

> **User Account Control**
>
> Under UAC, accounts in the local Administrators group have two access tokens, one with standard user privileges and one with administrator privileges. Because of UAC access token filtering, a script is normally run under the standard user token, unless it is run "as an Administrator" in elevated privilege mode. Not all scripts required administrative privileges.
>
> Scripts cannot determine programmatically whether they are running under a standard user security token or an Administrator token. The script may fail with an access denied error. If the script requires administrator privileges, then it must be run in the elevated mode. Access to WMI namespaces differs depending on whether the script is run in elevated mode. Some WMI operations, such as getting data or executing most methods, do not require that the account run as an administrator. For more information about default access permissions, see Access to WMI Namespaces and Executing Privileged Operations.
>
> **Wmic**
> The first time you run Wmic after system installation, it must be run from an elevated command prompt. The elevated mode may not be required for subsequent executions of Wmic unless the WMI operations require administrator privilege.

**Use WMIC**

```
wmic netuse get /format:list
```

gives you what's available.

Use something like

```
wmic netuse get remotepath, localname /format:list
```

To put the output in a file or on the clipboard.

**WMIC specific switch**

---

`/output` or `/append`

eg

```
wmic /node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt" /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\EventLog.html" /failfast:on PATH Win32_NTLogEvent where  (EventIDentifier=42 or eventidentifier=1003) get /format:hform
```

(/node is a list of IP addresses and/or computer names of computers to run the command against, one IP address or computer name per line)

**General Command Prompt File Redirection**

---

Appending >filename.ext (or >>filename.ext to append to a file)to a command writes the output to the file rather than the screen.

```
wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,model,partnumber>MotherboardPartNum.txt
```

**General Command Prompt Piping**

---

Appending |command sends the output to a command rather than the screen. The usefull commands that output is sent to are

```
find or findstr (finds and filters text)

sort (sorts the output)

more (displays output to screen one page at a time)

clip (puts output onto the clipboard)

null (makes the data disappear for good - used for unwanted error messages)


wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,model,partnumber|clip
```

**Combining Piping and Redirection**

---

So we can combine them. To send the list to a file on the desktop in reversed sort order (z to a) with blank lines removed.

```
wmic service get name,displayname /format:list|findstr .|sort /r>"%userprofile%\desktop\services_reversed.txt"
```

**WMIC Output Options**

---

The output options are

```
/Format:list (a list - use notepad to view)

/format:table (a table - use notepad to view)

/format:hform (an html list - name the file's extension .html so IE will show)

/format:htable (an html table - name the file's extension .html so IE will show)

/format:csv (comma seperated variable - used for importing data into other programs such as excel)
```

also `value, mof, rawxml`, and `xml`.

So,

```
sort /?

find /?

findstr /?

more /?

clip /?
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in the output of `net use`

- The `Status` field can hold information or be empty.
- The `Network` field can have multiple values depending of network mapping. In my case i have "Microsoft Windows Network" and "Netware Services". So, there is no direct substitution.
- The `Network` field can be in the same line that the `Remote` field or can be on the next line, and as the `Remote` field may include spaces, checking the character at the column limit position is not reliable. It is necessary to delay the check until the next line is readed to determine if it contains remote data.

So, not a one liner to handle it

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "drive="
    for /f "skip=6 tokens=1,* delims=\" %%a in ('net use') do (
        if defined drive (
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            if "%%b"=="" (
                echo !drive! !networkPath!
            ) else (
                echo !drive! !networkPath:~0,26!
            )
            endlocal
            set "drive="
        )
        if not "%%b"=="" for /f "tokens=2" %%c in ("x%%a") do (
            set "drive=%%c"
            set "networkPath=\\%%b"
        )
    )
```

`%%a` loop will read the lines from `net use` and split them using a backslash as delimiter. This will allow us to determine if the line contains or not a network path (if there is no second token, the line did not contain a backslash).

As we are delaying the output of the information in one line until the next is readed (to determine if the remote path continues in the `Network` column), the first operation inside the `for` loop is to determine if we have data pending from previous loop. If there is data, depending on the content of the current line we select what to output.

Once the data is echoed, if the current line contains network information, it is saved for later output.

This is the faster solution, but there are two alternatives that require less code:

**multiple `net use`** commands

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem For each line in the output of the net use that includes a drive letter
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('net use^|find ":"') do (
        rem Retrieve the drive letter from the line
        for /f "tokens=2" %%b in ("x%%a") do (
            rem Run a net use with the drive letter and output the drive and the path
            for /f "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%c in ('net use %%b') do if not "%%d"=="" echo(%%b \\%%d
        )
    )
```

Less code, but as multiple `net use` commands are executed, it is slower

**Use WMIC**

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic netuse get LocalName^, RemoteName^, Status /format:csv ^| find ":"'
    ) do echo(%%a %%b
```

Less code, but in this case, adminitrator righs are required to run the command

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late but this helped me

```
WMIC NETUSE GET LocalName, RemotePath /FORMAT:TABLE | FIND /i ":"
```